# how to install implemented python code on to a host

Tags: python, sdn

**The ARP Trigger Module is implemented and installed in every hosts in the
network using Python. The algorithm for the function is as follows**
ARP_Trig()
{[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b19UB.png)

in the above line it stated that python code is installed on every host.so please suggest how to install implemented code on to a host

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps: https://pypi.org/project/arprequest/
More specifically: python3 -m pip install arprequest

HTH